# Moving customers and orders between CE and EE

Tags: magento-enterprise, orders, customer, migration

My client decided to merge Magento instances and migrate customers (and orders) from CE to EE. I have analyzed several options from custom plugins to database level migration and each approach has some cons. Here are the issues I see:

- afer migration customer may not be able to login (different password encryption)
- data model changes between CE and EE

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

About the encryption you can implement an observer which checks for the password with both ways and then logs you in, I implemented something alike here: https://github.com/ikonoshirt/pbkdf2, it is compatible with CE and EE but not at the same time, so might need some work.

Data model is the same, so in my opinion the passwords are the only problem. Or do you mean the attributes you created are different? Then you need a mapping or create them both.

Answer (score 0):

Magento EE actually handles this quite well.

The encryption scheme updates the existing passwords and encrypted configuration data with stronger hashing and encryption algorithms which automatically migrate from CE to EE.

Going the other way (EE=>CE) is not supported and has some issues such as customer and admin passwords needing to be reset and encrypted fields such as system configuration data being unable to be decrypted.